# How to find duplicate lines of code in Xcode

Tags: xcode, swift

When I am making applications in Xcode, I sometimes find that I write duplicate code.

Is there a way in Xcode to find duplicate code in all files? I would like to know this because I would put the code into a function instead.

Comment: @pjctech Swift. Added it as a tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not in Xcode itself, but there are third party solutions. They both can analyse Swift code.

1. [PMD](https://pmd.github.io), it includes CPD, the copy-paste-detector.
2. [jscpd](https://github.com/kucherenko/jscpd), a copy/paste detector for programming source code